# Telegram bot stops responding

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I am developing a telegram bot using a popular wrapper from [GitHub](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and I faced some unexpected behavior. The bot stops responding after a certain period of time. After some time (may be hours) it can wake up and start responding. It is hosted on Ubuntu Server on Amazon cloud. Here are error logs:

> BotApi-0 (err): 2017-02-24 05:25 +00:00: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
>
> BotApi-0 (err):   "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
>
> BotApi-0 (err): 2017-02-24 05:25 +00:00: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:334: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>
> BotApi-0 (err):   SNIMissingWarning
>
> BotApi-0 (err): 2017-02-24 05:25 +00:00: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:132: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
>
> BotApi-0 (err):   InsecurePlatformWarning

What are the steps to debug it? Is it missing SSL which causes this behavior?

**UPDATE Feb28 2017**

- Updated Python to latest version
- Analyzed packet dumps through Wireshark, no errors were found, seems like all requests to Telegram API are 200 OK

Comment: Ok, I have updated python to newest possible version, let's see if it helps

Comment: Try to check, that your backend respond 200 OK on every request from telegram.

Comment: @DanilPyatnitsev updated question. No problematic packets were found. Even the example from the wrapper's GitHub page works in the same way (however, looks like it is so only in my case).